# Bootstrap Carousel not sliding on Safari web browser and iPad/iPhone

Tags: iphone, twitter-bootstrap, ipad, safari, carousel

Its sliding on other browser, but in Safari it change the image but not sliding.

I tried this code and also transition.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#Carousel').carousel({
            interval:   1000
        });
    });

[data-slide-to] {
cursor: pointer;
}

$('.carousel').carousel()

$('.carousel').carousel('cycle');
```

Answer (score 0):

A little late ... but i fixed it by placing a block element with negative margin into each carousel item.

like so:

```
<div style="margin: 0 -5px">&nbsp;</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is quite simple. All animations on iphone are sometimes blocked because of the **accessibility settings**.

You have to go to :

```
 settings > accessibility > animation
```

Then **uncheck** "**Reduce animations**".