# Why isn't my Bootstrap carousel or jQuery code working in Safari?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, safari, mobile-safari, bootstrap-carousel

I've been coding for a month so sorry if this has an easy answer, but I've been searching for days with no result.

I've built a simple practise webpage using a Bootstrap carousel as the page background and jQuery to make divs (where page content will eventually go) appear. When I open the HTML file in Chrome, Firefox and Opera the page works fine, but when the file is opened in Safari on an iPhone or iPad, the links to the divs don't work (when clicked, nothing appears) and the Carousel doesn't work at all, instead appearing as four separate images down the page with simple 'previous' and 'next' links appearing at the bottom of the page. Unfortunately I have no way to test the page on a desktop version of Safari. I feel like there's something simple I'm missing but I can't figure it out. Thanks in advance. Below is the entire code for my site (CSS, HTML and jQuery), and here is a jsFiddle of the page: https://jsfiddle.net/fh8pxqqt/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">



<link rel="icon" type="image/png"  href="http://res.cloudinary.com/jamesddavies/image/upload/v1469359895/strohl_logo_bod9yw.png"/>


<title>Alex Strohl</title>

<style>

#bg-wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

/*Carousel Background*/

#carousel-bg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.carousel-inner > .item > img, .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    object-fit: cover;
    -webkit-object-fit: cover;
    -o-object-fit: cover;
    -moz-object-fit: cover;
}

/*Nav*/

nav {

}

ul {
    height: 75px;
    line-height: 50px;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
    text-align: left;
    padding: 10px;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

ul:hover {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    transition: 500ms;
    -webkit-transition: 500ms;
    -o-transition: 500ms;
    -moz-transition: 500ms;
}

ul:not(:hover) {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
    transition: 500ms;
    -webkit-transition: 500ms;
    -o-transition: 500ms;
    -moz-transition: 500ms;
}

ul img {
    padding-right: 30px;
    padding-left: 30px;

}

ul img:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter:Alpha(opacity=50);
    transition: 300ms;
    -webkit-transition: 300ms;
    -o-transition: 300ms;
    -moz-transition: 300ms;
}

ul img:not(:hover) {
    opacity: 1;
    filter:Alpha(opacity=50);
    transition: 300ms;
    -webkit-transition: 300ms;
    -o-transition: 300ms;
    -moz-transition: 300ms;
}

li {
    color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
    text-decoration: none;
}

.link:focus {
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    text-decoration: none;
}

.link:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    transition: 300ms;
    -webkit-transition: 300ms;
    -o-transition: 300ms;
    -moz-transition: 300ms;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.link:not(:hover) {
    color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
    transition: 300ms;
    -webkit-transition: 300ms;
    -o-transition: 300ms;
    -moz-transition: 300ms;
}

.link:click {
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

li {
    display: inline;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: normal;
    padding: 10px;
    z-index: 1;
}

li img {
    height: 50px;
    width: auto;
}



/*adventures*/

#adventures-wrapper {
    text-align: center;
}

.adventures {
    width: 80%;
    height: 70%;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
    color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
    position: absolute;
    top: 120px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index: 1;
    display: none;
}

/*commissions*/

#commissions-wrapper {
    text-align: center;
}

.commissions {
    width: 80%;
    height: 70%;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
    color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
    position: absolute;
    top: 120px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index: 1;
    display: none;
}

/*book*/

#book-wrapper {
    text-align: center;
}

.book {
    width: 80%;
    height: 70%;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
    color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
    position: absolute;
    top: 120px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index: 1;
    display: none;
}

/*alex*/

#alex-wrapper {
    text-align: center;
}

.alex {
    width: 80%;
    height: 70%;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
    color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
    position: absolute;
    top: 120px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index: 1;
    display: none;
}

/*contact*/

#contact-wrapper {
    text-align: center;
}

.contact {
    width: 80%;
    height: 70%;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
    color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
    position: absolute;
    top: 120px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index: 1;
    display: none;
}

/*responsive design*/

@media (max-width: 1000px){

    ul {
        text-align: center;
    }

}


</style>

</head>

<body>


<div id="bg-wrapper">   

    <!--Navbar-->

    <div class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/jamesddavies/image/upload/v1469359895/strohl_logo_bod9yw.png"></li>
            <li class="link adventures-link">Adventures</li>
            <li class="link commissions-link">Commissions</li>
            <li class="link book-link">Book</li>
            <li class="link alex-link">Alex</li>
            <li class="link contact-link">Contact</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <!--Adventures-->

    <div id="adventures-wrapper">
    <div class="adventures">
            <h1>Adventures</h1>
    </div>
    </div>

    <!--Commissions-->

    <div id="commissions-wrapper">
    <div class="commissions">
            <h1>Commissions</h1>
    </div>
    </div>

    <!--Book-->

    <div id="book-wrapper">
    <div class="book">
            <h1>Book</h1>
    </div>
    </div>

    <!--Alex-->

    <div id="alex-wrapper">
    <div class="alex">
            <h1>Alex</h1>
    </div>
    </div>

    <!--Contact-->

    <div id="contact-wrapper">
    <div class="contact">
            <h1>Contact</h1>
    </div>
    </div>

<!--Carousel background-->

<div id="carousel-bg" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-pause="false">

    <!--Indicators-->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators hidden">
        <li data-target="#carousel-bg" data-slide-to="0" class="active"> </li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-bg" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-bg" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-bg" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>

    <!--Wrapper for slides-->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/jamesddavies/image/upload/v1469264082/STROHL__MG_1150-Edit_wdcn2g.jpg">
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/jamesddavies/image/upload/v1469264097/_ST_3667_ob8jtb.jpg">
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/jamesddavies/image/upload/v1469264105/_ST_4081_yb2vdd.jpg">
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/jamesddavies/image/upload/v1469264128/_ST_9411_h9ftou.jpg">
        </div>

    </div>

    <!--Left and Right controls-->
    <a class="left carousel-control hidden" href="#carousel-bg" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>

    <a class="right carousel-control hidden" href="#carousel-bg"  role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"> </span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>


</div>      



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<script>

/*Link functionality*/

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#carousel-bg").click(function(){
            $(".adventures, .commissions, .book, .alex, .contact").hide(500);
        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".adventures-link").click(function(){
            $(".adventures").toggle(500);
            $(".commissions, .book, .alex, .contact").hide(500);
        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".commissions-link").click(function(){
            $(".commissions").toggle(500);
            $(".adventures, .book, .alex, .contact").hide(500);
        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".book-link").click(function(){
            $(".book").toggle(500);
            $(".adventures, .commissions, .alex, .contact").hide(500);
        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".alex-link").click(function(){
            $(".alex").toggle(500);
            $(".adventures, .commissions, .book, .contact").hide(500);
        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".contact-link").click(function(){
            $(".contact").toggle(500);
            $(".adventures, .commissions, .book, .alex").hide(500);
        });
    });

</script>

</body>
```

Comment: Can you please create a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Hi - here's the jsFiddle. I'll add it to the main post too. - https://jsfiddle.net/fh8pxqqt/

Comment: It's not exactly clear what issues you're having to be honest, maybe an image would help. Your previous & next arrows aren't visible because you applied `hidden` to them; see responsive [utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes) and here are two screenshots from an [iPhone](https://imgur.com/a/6Rh3q). Also, make sure to check your console for any errors.

Comment: Thanks for the screenshots - that's actually how the website should look in its current state, which makes me question the devices rather than my code. Did you just input my code into a text editor and run the file in Safari? No clue why it isn't working on my devices if that's the case

Comment: I dont know why but - [this helped me!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27417877/bootstrap-carousel-not-sliding-on-safari-web-browser-and-ipad-iphone#answer-49392255)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried opening your website in iphone chrome browser? I think you are not loading your javascript files when your opening the html file in mobile. Your code is  working in safari. I have tested it.

Open the below link in your mobile browser. see if it works or not.

https://output.jsbin.com/cugawimabo

Comment: Thanks so much - looks like the JS files just weren't loading when opening the HTML file as you said. Rookie mistake. Much appreciated